# Passing a method from directive to factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, angular-services, angular-controller

I'm trying to pass a method that is defined in the controller, via a directive to a factory. I seem not to be able to fully understand scoping or the best way to do this.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="testController as tc">
    <h1>Testing from directive -> factory</h1>
    <test-directive todo="doSomething()"> </test-directive>
    <button ng-click="tc.executeSomething()">DO IT!</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);

app.controller('testController',[
    'testFactory',
    function(testFactory){
        var self = this;

        $scope.doSomething = function(){
            alert('success!');
        }

        self.executeSomething = testFactory.delegate();
}]);


app.directive('testDirective',['testFactory'
    function(testFactory){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { todo = '&' },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            if(attr.todo){
                testFactory.delegate = scope.todo;
            }            
        }
    }
}]);


app.factory('testFactory',[
    function(){
        return {
            delegate: function();
        }
}]);
```

Comment: Do you wanted to provide implementation of method from directive..or something else? But the way you are doing seems very incorrect..

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, what you need to do is add a scope binding/parameter in the directive definition and then pass that in when you invoke it.

Comment: The implementation should be defined in the controller... each will be slightly different. What I hope to do is to pass that defined function, delegate, to a factory where it will be executed or assigned to external libraries such as JQueryUI.